# JMH start script -> e.g. set Iterations(5)

Tags: java, jmh

When I start my Benchmark I will only have 5 warmupInterations, 5 measurementIterations and only 1 fork. *I don't want to use the commandline options !*

```
**my test code in Eclipse:**

package org.sample;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.BenchmarkMode;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Mode;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.OutputTimeUnit;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.RunnerException;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.Options;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.OptionsBuilder;

public class MyBenchmark {

    @Benchmark @BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput) @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    public String[] testMethod() {
        return "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10".split(",");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
                .include(MyBenchmark.class.getSimpleName())
                .warmupIterations(5)
                .measurementIterations(5)
                .forks(1)
                .build();

        new Runner(opt).run();
    }

}
```

Then I say

```
mvn clean install
java -jar benchmark.jar
```

And I get the same ouput as always (no changed iterations or fork !!)

```
C:\Users\SPARK\Desktop\workspace\jmhBenchmark\target>java -jar benchmarks.jar
# JMH 1.11.3 (released 68 days ago)
# VM version: JDK 1.8.0_74, VM 25.74-b02
# VM invoker: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_74\bin\java.exe
# VM options: <none>
# Warmup: 20 iterations, 1 s each
# Measurement: 20 iterations, 1 s each
# Timeout: 10 min per iteration
# Threads: 1 thread, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Throughput, ops/time
# Benchmark: org.sample.MyBenchmark.testMethod

# Run progress: 0,00% complete, ETA 00:06:40
# Fork: 1 of 10
# Warmup Iteration   1: 2108087,328 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   2: 2435219,249 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   3: 2589289,173 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   4: 2606293,767 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   5: 2548095,405 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   6: 2594874,969 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   7: 2583629,760 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   8: 2579041,971 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   9: 2580402,155 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration  10: 2546640,733 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration  11: 2580002,548 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration  12:
```

What I am doing wrong ??

Thanks a lot for reading

Comment: Had you already a look to my answer? Could it solve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By executing `java -jar benchmark.jar` the tests are executed using the default JMH settings.

If you want to run the test using the settings specified by your `OptionsBuilder`. You have to run it as `java -cp benchmark.jar org.sample.MyBenchmark`.

Find a complete example below.

```
mvn archetype:generate \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.openjdk.jmh \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=jmh-java-benchmark-archetype \
    -DgroupId=org.sample \
    -DartifactId=jmh-example \
    -Dversion=0.0.1 \
    -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Replace the file `src/main/java/org/sample/MyBenchmark.java` with your source.

executing `java -jar target/benchamrks.jar` use following settings

```
# VM options: <none>
# Warmup: 20 iterations, 1 s each
# Measurement: 20 iterations, 1 s each
# Timeout: 10 min per iteration
# Threads: 1 thread, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Throughput, ops/time
# Benchmark: org.sample.MyBenchmark.testMethod
...
# Fork: 1 of 10
```

executing `java -cp target/benchmarks.jar org.sample.MyBenchmark` use following settings

```
# VM options: <none>
# Warmup: 5 iterations, 1 s each
# Measurement: 5 iterations, 1 s each
# Timeout: 10 min per iteration
# Threads: 1 thread, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Throughput, ops/time
# Benchmark: org.sample.MyBenchmark.testMethod
...
# Fork: 1 of 1
```